# Fix for scp: .: not a regular file

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, scp

I am trying to write a shell function to scp a file to my AWS host

```
function ec2-scp() {
    scp -i /path/to/pem/file.pem $1 user@ec2.host.amazonaws.com:.
}
```

I am using it as

```
ec2-scp server.war
```

And I am getting an error:

```
scp: .: not a regular file
```

But when I replace the $1 by the file name and execute the same, it works.
It's a war file that I am trying to SCP. How can i fix this?

Comment: If you run `set -x; ec2-scp server.war; set +x` with the function taking the argument what command do you see running? Does just removing the `.` help?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about set -+x. I see this getting execute: scp -i  /path/to/pem/file.pem user@ec2.host.amazonaws.com:. server.war , now how do I get server.war in it's correct place?

Comment: That output isn't really possible given the function as written. What does `type ec2-scp` say the body of the function is? Is the body of the function perhaps `scp -i /path/to/pem/file.pem user@ec2.host.amazonaws.com:. $1` by accident?

Comment: That looks correct,Output: ec2-scp is a function
ec2-scp () 
{ 
    scp -i /path/to/pem/file.pem $1 host@ip:.
}

Comment: There isn't any way with the function written that way for the argument given to `ec2-scp` to be at the end of the arguments passed to `scp`. Are you sure that's the function body you get in the same shell session where `set -x` reports that the file is at the end? Do you perhaps have an old `ec2-scp` alias lying around? (I'd have expected `type ec2-scp` to report that instead of the function body though if that was the case.)

Comment: This is weird, but somehow it worked now. not sure what I did to get it working, I was trying out somethings to get this working. could be reload issue, not sure. Anyway, Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: It works with the function in the post? I'm still betting on you having an incorrect function definition in the shell that was trying before. That's why I asked about whether the same shell session was having the problem as displaying that function body but <shrug>.

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the trailing dot like this:

```
function ec2-scp() {
    scp -i /path/to/pem/file.pem $1 user@ec2.host.amazonaws.com:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is server.war a link ? because symbolic links are not regular files.
Try reading this as well https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52634/error-using-scp-not-a-regular-file

Answer (score 0):

According to [user48435 answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93410) - just add -r
like:
`scp -i -r /path/to/pem/file.pem $1 user@ec2.host.amazonaws.com:.`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to upload an `xcarchive` file but this is actually a directory. You can upload it with the `-r` flag (to recursively upload the contents of the archvie), or better yet compress the xcarchive to a zip and upload that instead.

Answer (score -1):

I use `scp -r -i` and its working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Munna Biswas, please double check that my edit with the purpose of turning something which gives a "thanks" impression into a (code-only) answer, did not break the purpose of your post. If you did only want to say thanks please simply delete this post.